# NoClassDefFoundError: caused by ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

My program may use a library when it is present at runtime, but it is not required to have this library to run the program. However, when I run my program (without the library being present), it complains that it is not present for a very specific import:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: nl/lolmewn/stats/api/storage/StorageException
        at me.staartvin.plugins.pluginlibrary.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:34) ~[?:?]
        at me.staartvin.plugins.pluginlibrary.PluginLibrary.loadLibraries(PluginLibrary.java:105) ~[?:?]
        at me.staartvin.plugins.pluginlibrary.PluginLibrary.onEnable(PluginLibrary.java:68) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:264) ~[spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-eadd615-4509a14]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:337) [spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-eadd615-4
9a14]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:403) [spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-eadd615-
09a14]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:381) [spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-eadd615-45
a14]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:330) [spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-eadd615-4
9a14]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.t(MinecraftServer.java:422) [spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-eadd615-4509a14
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.l(MinecraftServer.java:383) [spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-eadd615-4509a14
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:338) [spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-eadd615-4509a14
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:272) [spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-eadd615-4509
4]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:545) [spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-eadd615-4509a
]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Uenter code herenknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nl.lolmewn.stats.api.storage.StorageException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:152) ~[spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-eadd615-4
9a14]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:100) ~[spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-eadd615-4
9a14]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
        ... 14 more
```

The code that uses this *StorageException* class is this:

```java
try {
    user = stats.getUserManager().loadUser(player.getUniqueId(), stats.getStatManager());
} catch (StorageException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that I have many imports using this library. The odd thing is that **when I leave out the *StorageException* import** (e.g. change it to a general *Exception*), **it does not give any error anymore, even though there are other imports** (from the exact same library) **present**!

Obviously, I want to use the StorageException class for catching errors, but I can't seem to do this.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: class is OK at compilation stage, but cannot be found at execution (if any server exist - follow documenattion)

Comment: @JacekCz Why does it only occur for the StorageException class, not for other classes?